# AutoMapper ProjectTo on object fields with the same name but different types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, .net-6.0, automapper-11

I am projecting the result of an entity framework database call into a new object type.

```
await _db.Type1
.ProjectTo<Type2>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The Type2 object has the following field on it where the type is an Enum.

```
CategoryType CategoryType {get; set;}
```

Type 1 has a virtual member with the same name, but the type is not an enum, it's a separate object type.

```
 public virtual CategoryType CategoryType { get; set; }
```

`Type1.CategoryType` is an object with additional information that relates to the enum.

The problem is, AutoMapper ProjectTo is automatically trying to map `Type1.CategoryType` to `Type2.Category Type` and throwing an error `Unable to map expression from Type1.CategoryType to Type2.CategoryType)`. This makes sense because they are different object types.

I am already mapping a different field to `Type2.CategoryType` in the mapping configuration using the following mapping technique.

```
.ForCtorParam(nameof(Type2.CategoryType), opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CategoryTypeId))
```

But how do I prevent AutoMapper from trying to map `Type1.CategoryType` to `Type2.CategoryType` even though the fields have the same name?

I tried using `.ForSourceMember(x => x.CategoryType, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());` but AutoMapper is still trying to map the two types.

IS there a way to accomplish this without changing the names of one of the fields?

Comment: Upgrade AM. If that still doesn't work, a repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail. You can also remove the setter.

Comment: How would you write the `Select` without AutoMapper?